# Data from all the dynamically generated input fields doesn't go to database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dom-events

I regenerate the input fields by calling an external PHP function which generates those fields with the help an ajax function, but the save function doesn't save data from all the fields but only the data from last row is saved to database..

Code for ajax function to regenerate these fields looks like this:

```
var counter = 0;    
function loadfields_addmore(checked)
{
$jd.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>",
  type: "POST",
  data: {'option':'com_joomd', 'view':'itempanel', 'task':'loadfields', 'typeid':<?php echo $this->cparams->typeid; ?>, 'catid[]':checked, 'id':<?php echo (int)$this->item->id; ?>, "<?php echo jutility::getToken(); ?>":1, 'abase':1}
    });
}
```

For save button that triggers the save process:

```
function save(task) {
var data = $jd("form[name='<?php echo $array['editform']; ?>']").serializeArray();
$jd.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo $url; ?>",
      type: "POST",
      dataType:"json",
      data: data
});
}
```

The actual save function is like this:

```
function store()
{
    foreach($post['cats'] as $cat)  {

    $query = 'insert into #__joomd_item_cat values('.$cat.', '.$row->id.')';
    $this->_db->setQuery( $query );
}
}
```

The image shows the form..[image: As shown in the attachment..]
The data from all the fields is not going to the database..

Comment: Remember the serialization is already being done.. i've tried a dynamic div id for new fields which didn't work

Comment: Hey check your form elements.are you giving them dynamic id..?

Comment: not in the code.. but i've tried that

Comment: Why the question becomes obsolete after initial responses.. And no one else try to answer the same..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it seems like some form elements are created on the fly through jQuery. These will not be posted as they are not part of the original source code but were added later.

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to get fields that were created on the fly.
Your parameters will be 'click',buttonid,next static parent of button.

Comment: am not using jquery here.. which will require complete reshuffling.. 

By the way.. the data from last row which may be on the fly generated row is posted perfectly.. but any data before last row is not posted..

Comment: Why the question becomes obsolete after initial responses.. And no one else try to answer the same..